# Creating an API using Django-Rest-Framework with join tables

Tags: mysql, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have the following MySQL tables:
-Make
-Model
-Styles

models.py (auto generated)

```
class Makes(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=13)
  nicename = models.CharField(db_column='niceName', max_length=13)
  class Meta:
      managed = False
      db_table = 'Makes'


class Models(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=23)
    nicename = models.CharField(db_column='niceName', max_length=23)
    make =  models.ForeignKey(Makes, models.DO_NOTHING)
    class Meta:
      managed = False
      db_table = 'Models'
```

serializers.py

```
class MakeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


  class Meta:
    model = Makes
    fields = ('name',)


class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


make = MakeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Models
    fields = ('make','id', 'name', 'nicename')
```

views.py

```
class MakesList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     queryset = Makes.objects.all()
     serializer_class = MakeSerializer

class MakesDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
     queryset = Makes.objects.all()
     serializer_class = MakeSerializer
```

In other words, Styles is the parent table that contains an ID for Make and Model which connects the two.

How do I go about making a relationship with DRF to give me the expected output:

```
    "makes": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Acura",
    "models": [{
        "id": "Acura_ILX",
        "name": "ILX",
        "styles": [{
                  "id": "1"
                  "name": "Sport"
                  }]
    }, {
        "id": "Acura_ILX_Hybrid",
        "name": "ILX Hybrid",
        "styles": [{
                  "id": "1"
                  "name": "Sport"
                  }]
    }, {
        "id": "Acura_MDX",
        "name": "MDX",
        "styles": [{
                  "id": "1"
                  "name": "Sport"
                  }]
        }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically what you have to do is create a bunch of serializers.

```
class MakeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Make
        fields = ('your', 'fields', 'here')

class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    make = MakeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('name', 'just_fields_here')

class StyleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = ModelSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Style
        fields = ('your_fields_here_again', )
```

This is how your serializers could look like in the simples way.

And this is how you could use it:

```
>>> make = Make.objects.create(name="Audi")
>>> model1 = Model.objects.create(make=make, name='R8')
>>> model2 = Model.objects.create(make=make, name='Q7')
>>> Style.objects.create(model=model1, name='Sport')
>>> Style.objects.create(model=model2, name='SUV')

>>> serializer = MakeSerializer(instance=make)
```

and by using

```
>>> serializer.data
```

you output should look like this:

```
{
    'name': 'Audi',
    'model': [{
        'name': 'R8',
        'style': {
            'name': 'Sport'
        }
    },{
        'name': 'Q7',
        'style': {
            'name': 'SUV'
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: It's just an example. If you have data populated just create those serializers. Download one object, which you are interested with, and pass it to serializer as instance